# Find association rules in SQL Server

Tags: sql

Database:

```
Transaction  ProductID
 1              1000
 2              1000
 2              1001 
 3              1000
 3              1002
 4              1000
 4              1001
 5              1003
```

and L1 table (i keep Frequenties item)

```
PRODUCTID  SUPPORT
  1000       4
  1001       2
  1002       1
  1003       1
```

According to L1 table, how to find this result with a T-SQL statement? And find support value from  my Transaction table?

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------------+
| PRODUCTID1  | PRODUCTID2|     SUPPORT     |
+-------------+-----------+-----------------+
|      1000   |   1001    |         2       |
+-------------+-----------+-----------------+
|      1000   |   1002    |         1       |
+-------------+-----------+-----------------+
|      1000   |   1003    |         0       |
+-------------+-----------+-----------------+
|      1001   |   1002    |         0       |
+-------------+-----------+-----------------+
|      1001   |   1003    |         0       |
+-------------+-----------+-----------------+
|      1002   |   1003    |         0       |,
+-------------+-----------+-----------------+
```

Test Table:

```
create table transactions(
   ORDERID    INT,
   PRODUCTID INT
);

insert into transactions(ORDERID, PRODUCTID)
values ('1', '1000')
      ,('2', '1000')
      ,('2', '1001')
      ,('3', '1000')
      ,('3', '1002')
      ,('4', '1000')
      ,('4', '1001'),
       ('5', '1003');

  CREATE TABLE L1
(PRODUCTID INT,
SUPPORT INT )

 INSERT INTO L1 (PRODUCTID,SUPPORT)
   SELECT PRODUCTID,COUNT(*) [SUPPORT] FROM transactions
                    GROUP BY PRODUCTID                        
                    ORDER BY PRODUCTID
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By what logic is the Support column produced?

Comment: E.g., why doesn't the row `(1000,1003)` have a Support value of 1?

Comment: What is this trying to accomplish ?

Comment: support means count in current table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH Pairs 
     As (SELECT A.PRODUCTID AS PRODUCTID1, 
                B.PRODUCTID AS PRODUCTID2 
         FROM   L1 A 
                JOIN L1 B 
                  ON A.PRODUCTID < B.PRODUCTID) 
SELECT PRODUCTID1, 
       PRODUCTID2, 
       COUNT(t2.ORDERID) AS SUPPORT
FROM   Pairs 
       LEFT JOIN transactions t1 
         ON t1.PRODUCTID = PRODUCTID1 
       LEFT JOIN transactions t2 
         ON t2.PRODUCTID = PRODUCTID2 
            AND t1.ORDERID = t2.ORDERID 
GROUP  BY PRODUCTID1, 
          PRODUCTID2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Product1.ProductId, Product2.ProductId, Count( T.OrderId ) As Support
From L1 As Product1
    Join L1 As Product2 
        On Product2.ProductId > Product1.ProductId
    Left Join   (
                Select T1.OrderId, T1.ProductId As Product1, T2.ProductId As Product2
                From Transactions As T1
                    Join Transactions As T2
                        On T2.OrderId = T1.OrderId
                            And T2.ProductId > T1.ProductId
                ) As T
        On T.Product1 = Product1.ProductId
            And T.Product2 = Product2.ProductId
Group BY Product1.ProductId, Product2.ProductId
```